# Room Transaction rollback

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

Accordording to the [room documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Transaction) transaction rollsback every query in a transaction in case an error occurs.

So here I tested the rollback out:

```
@Transaction
public Completable updateTable1(Table table1) {
    return Completable.fromAction(
            () -> 
                table1.setNotice("why am i updateed????");
                synchronousUpdate(table1);
                table1.setForeignKeyId(90); //some random foreign key which does not exsist so it throws an exception
                synchronousUpdate(table1);
            }
    );
}

@Update
void synchronousUpdate(T obj);
```

my table1 still gets updated even when the second update throws an error.

What can the cause be? I is cause I return a completable rather than a synchronous return value like void?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentations says

> The transaction will be marked as successful unless an exception is thrown in the method body.

It doesn't actually say that ***the exception will be managed***, although the ROLLBACK will i.e. the setTransactionSuccessful is skipped and the endTransaction is executed. If you look at the generated code, say for example the coded method is :-

```
@Transaction
public boolean update4(Bookmark b1, Bookmark b2) {
    if (update(b1) > 0) {
        if (update(b2) < 1) {
            abort(b1);
            return false;
        }
    } else {
            abort(b1);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The code generated by Room is :-

```
  @Override
  public boolean update4(final Bookmark b1, final Bookmark b2) {
    __db.beginTransaction();
    try {
      boolean _result = AllDao_Impl.super.update4(b1, b2);
      __db.setTransactionSuccessful();
      return _result;
    } finally {
      __db.endTransaction();
    }
  }
```

there is no **catch**, so you need to handle exceptions accordingly.

Consider the following (modified version of the previous answer given):-

```
    b1.setPostUrl("YetAnotherURL");
    b5.setPostTitle("P5");
    b5.setPostUrl("U5");
    try {
        dao.update4(b1, b5);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    logInfo("-D1");
    dao.update4(b1,b5);
    logInfo("-D2");
```

Basically the same update, *which will not update (return 0) as the id doesn't exist*, run twice. The difference being that the first is in a try/catch block.

The result from the log :-

```
2021-07-09 12:04:38.344 W/System.err: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: mylist_data.ID (code 1555 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY)
2021-07-09 12:04:38.348 W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
2021-07-09 12:04:38.349 W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:796)
2021-07-09 12:04:38.349 W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
2021-07-09 12:04:38.349 W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
2021-07-09 12:04:38.349 W/System.err:     at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteStatement.executeInsert(FrameworkSQLiteStatement.java:51)
2021-07-09 12:04:38.349 W/System.err:     at androidx.room.EntityInsertionAdapter.insertAndReturnId(EntityInsertionAdapter.java:114)
2021-07-09 12:04:38.349 W/System.err:     at a.a.so67958704javaroomconvertexistingdb.AllDao_Impl.abort(AllDao_Impl.java:133)
2021-07-09 12:04:38.349 W/System.err:     at a.a.so67958704javaroomconvertexistingdb.AllDao.update4(AllDao.java:40)
2021-07-09 12:04:38.350 W/System.err:     at a.a.so67958704javaroomconvertexistingdb.AllDao_Impl.access$001(AllDao_Impl.java:22)
2021-07-09 12:04:38.350 W/System.err:     at a.a.so67958704javaroomconvertexistingdb.AllDao_Impl.update4(AllDao_Impl.java:159)
2021-07-09 12:04:38.350 W/System.err:     at a.a.so67958704javaroomconvertexistingdb.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:78)
....
2021-07-09 12:04:38.353 D/BMINFO-D1: ID = 1 PostTitle = P1 PostURL =AnotherURL
2021-07-09 12:04:38.353 D/BMINFO-D1: ID = 2 PostTitle = P2 PostURL =U2
2021-07-09 12:04:38.353 D/BMINFO-D1: ID = 3 PostTitle = P3 PostURL =U3
2021-07-09 12:04:38.353 D/BMINFO-D1: ID = 4 PostTitle = P4 PostURL =U4
2021-07-09 12:04:38.355 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-07-09 12:04:38.358 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: a.a.so67958704javaroomconvertexistingdb, PID: 14230
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{a.a.so67958704javaroomconvertexistingdb/a.a.so67958704javaroomconvertexistingdb.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: mylist_data.ID (code 1555 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
```

Noting that the first exception is caught and printed and is NOT a FATAL EXCEPTION, the 2nd is.

Comment: I see, so since room does manage an occured exception it "assumes" the transaction is valid?

Comment: @FunnyMoments I'd put it more as that it manages the transaction correctly i.e. not leaving an incomplete  transaction, no matter what.

Comment: conserning the abort function in your example. how exactly does abort work in this case? is that like predefined function of room?

Comment: @FunnyMoments just an attempt to insert a duplicate with onConflict Strategy of ABORT (as per my previous answer) i.e. `@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.ABORT)
    abstract long abort(Bookmark bookmark);`. It's not a Room function.